# Error deploying AWS CDK stacks with Azure Pipelines (using python in CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-pipelines, aws-cdk

app.py example of how my stacks are defined (with some information changed as you can imagine)

```
Stack1(app, "Stack1",env=cdk.Environment(account='123456789', region='eu-west-1'))
```

In my azure pipeline I'm trying to do a cdk deploy

```
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'Service_connection_name'
    regionName: 'eu-west-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
    sudo bash -c "cdk deploy '*' -v --ci --require-approval-never"
  displayName: "Deploying CDK stacks"
```

but getting errors. I have the service connection to AWS configured, but the first error was

> [Stack_Name] failed: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account [Account_number], but no credentials have been configured

Stack_Name and Account_Number have been redacted

After this error, I decided to add a step to my pipeline and manually create the files .aws/config and .aws/credentials

```
- script: |
    echo "Preparing for CDK"
    echo "Creating directory"
    sudo bash -c "mkdir -p ~/.aws"
    echo "Writing to files"
    sudo bash -c "echo -e '[default]\nregion = $AWS_REGION\noutput = json' > ~/.aws/config"
    sudo bash -c "echo -e '[default]\naws_access_key_id = $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\naws_secret_access_key = $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' > ~/.aws/credentials"
  displayName: "Setting up files for CDK"
```

After this I believed the credentials would be fixed but it still failed. The verbose option revealed the following error amongst the output:

> Setting "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" environment variable to

So instead of setting the region to "eu-west-1" it is being set to nothing

I imagine I'm missing something, so please, educate me and help me get this working

Comment: And where are you getting the crecentials? What does `'Service_connection_name'` signify? Why do you need `sudo` to run `cdk deploy`?

Comment: @gshpychka In azure pipelines you can configure the connection to AWS (a service connection). The name of that connection (Service_connection_name) is passed as the parameter for the AWS credentials when running an AWS Shell Script. The sudo part is because I wasn't sure if the issue was the access to the .aws folder, so I just threw it there tbh

Comment: It's not working because you're launching a separate shell with `sudo`. Replace your inline script with just `cdk deploy` with the desired arguments and the environment variables will be passed to CDK.

Comment: @gshpychka Following what you said I started reviewing the "sudo"s all over my code. Guess what? I got more errors, but at the end? It worked :)  Obviously the unthoughtful way I was throwing my sudos was the issue. I need to review some of the errors and actually think where and why I need sudo, but it is working. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're launching separate instances of a shell with `sudo bash`, and they don't share the credential environment variables that the `AWSShellScript` task is populating.

To fix the credentials issue, replace the inline script with just `cdk deploy '*' -v --ci --require-approval never`